# Unity C# custom class values wont update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a difficult one to explain so bear with me, if you have any questions I can clarify.

In my game I use a [custom class to store items in an inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yUHt.png). A List of these objects makes up the players inventory.

In this particular case [I'm carrying out a transaction between the player and a store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7jgW.png). It works like so: (Follow along with a [bad drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrJVD.png))

> **y** represents the amount of an item in your inventory.
>
> > All that item is taken out, and split. Whatever isn't traded is sent back to **y**, which is where we get `y.setAmount(...)`.
> >
> > > The amount that IS traded is repackaged into `testItem` which has its Amount set by `ttsr.slider.value` which is a UI slider.

**THE PROBLEM:**

Is that when I run this code [testItem still shows an `Amount` of 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agGkl.png). And no matter how I seem to manipulate the variable I cant get an `InventoryItem` to change its `Amount` value

Comment: I would recommend to place a debug and check the value as the code runs. That tells you what values are used and where something would be missing.

Comment: Thats what I was trying to do with the Debug.log(...) right after i run the .setAmount() , It starts as 0 and ends as 0 after i use .setAmount(). Ive also tried just setting Amount equal to the number and still comes out as 0

Comment: Not Debug.Log but actually debug with breakpoints and VS attached to Unity https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html

Comment: Would it be bad of me to say "that In my decade and a half of programming experience i've never learned how to use a Debugger and at this point I'm too afraid to ask" ?

Comment: I use VS Code, is there any good tutorials on basic debugging in VS Code? The one on the unity website kind of expects you to know how to debug in the first place

Comment: The link i gave tells you how to run it